# Spyder 4 try-except NameError not working

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am defining a variable `test = 0` in Python 3.7.6 and then run the following code:

```
try:
    test
except NameError as error:
    print(error)
```

and I get the following output when running the code:

> name 'test' is not defined

The variable `test` however exists because I can call it in the console:

> In [11]: test
>
> Out[11]: 0

Any idea about what I am doing wrong there?

Best regards,

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for the delay in the reply. I am using Spyder 4.0.1 as IDE. I tried to reproduce the same error with Pyzo and I couldn't. So somehow it is linked with Spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late maybe, but if it can help someone else, the issue is discussed and solved [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11558). It is indeed an issue with Spyder 4. I could also not reproduce the behaviour with Spyder 3.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't reproduce your error, when test is defined.

```
test = 0
try:
    test
except NameError as error:
    print(error)
```

Now it works and there is no output. But if you try:

```
try:
    test
except NameError as error:
    print(error)
```

The output is now:

```
name 'a' is not defined
```

So probably your variable exists but you delete it later before you come to this code block. So the problem is definitely with the variable.

Comment: I am not running any more code than what I wrote above. First I run a single line setting `test` to 0 and then I delete this line and run the `try: ... except:` defined above. As mentioned above I can only reproduce the error with Spyder 4.0.1.